# Excel VBA: xlToRight then offset, then xlDown and offset again?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following:

- Select cell B3
- Select the furthest right value, then offset that two columns to the right
- Copy the value in that cell, then paste it to below the bottom value of the column the cell sits in.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
Range("B3").Select
'Select value 2 columns to the right of the last value in the row
Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2).Select
Selection.Copy
'Do the same again, this time paste that copied value at the bottom of the column that cell is in
Range("B3").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

However, there is an issue with the code on the line:

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
```

Which gives the error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-define error

I am not sure how I can instruct VBA to select not just the cell below the cell that is 2 columns to the right from the end of the row, but the last value in the column that cell sits in.

Comment: offset requires 2 parameters. (x,y) x- vertical, y - horizontal. positive values move right, down where as negative values move left, up.

Comment: @DougCoats both are optional inputs.  If left out they default to `0`

Comment: @ScottCraner Really? Thats brand new information.

Comment: @DougCoats https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel

Comment: I guess maybe the lack of the comma is confusing the compiler?

Comment: @DougCoats nope,  `...Offset(1)` will move the selection down one.  The issue is that the cell below `Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2).Select` is blank and the `Selection.End(xlDown).` is then moving to the bottom of the page and you cannot go one more row down than the bottom of the page.

Comment: @ScottCraner man it must be too early for me b/c i shouldve recognized that. Either way, good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the cell below `Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2).Select` is blank and the `Selection.End(xlDown)` is then moving to the bottom of the page and you cannot go one more row down than the bottom of the page.

Also avoid using `.Select` it slows the code down.

Use this:

```
With ActiveSheet
     .Range("B3").End(xlToRight).offset(,2).copy
     .cells(.rows.count,.Range("B3").End(xlToRight).offset(,2).column).end(xlUp).offset(1).PasteSpecial
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

With Selection.End(xlDown) you have probably reached bottom of the spreadsheet, then offset(1) brought you below the range. You should try to reach your target cell upward. See the code:

```
Dim refCl As Range
Dim srcCl As Range
Dim trgCl As Range

Set refCl = Range("B3")
Set srcCl = refCl.End(xlToRight).Offset(, 2)
Set trgCl = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, srcCl.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
trgCl.Value = srcCl.Value
```

BTW, using Select, Selection should be avoide. As I did.